# Questions about prototypes and method chaining

Tags: javascript

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I keep getting the following message in my console. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also if you guys have a better suggestion on how to handle this please let me know!

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

```
var animEngine = {};

animEngine.init = function () {
    'use strict';

    var elem = function(){};

    elem.prototype = {
        objType : '',
        objClass : '',
        objBackground: '',
        objWidth: '',
        objHeight: ''
    }

    var squareElem = Object.create(elem, {
        objType : {value: 'div'},
        objClass : {value: 'squareElement'},
        objBackground : {value: 'red'},
        objWidth : {value: '200px'},
        objHeight : {value: '200px'}
    });

    Function.prototype.method = function (name, fn) {
        this.prototype[name] = fn;
        return this;
    }

    squareElem.
                method('createObj', function () {
                    this.element = document.createElement(this.objType);
                    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.element);
                    this.element.className = this.objClass;
                    this.element.style.height = this.objHeight;
                    this.element.style.width = this.objWidth;
                    this.element.style.backgroundColor = this.objBackground;

                    return this;
                }).
                method('moveObj', function (x,y) {
                    this.element.style.position = 'relative';
                    this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
                    this.element.style.top = y + 'px';

                    return this;
                });

    squareElem.createObj().moveObj('100px', '100px');
};


animEngine.init();
```

Comment: You never define a squareElement object, yet you're trying to use it ?

Comment: I updated coded with the relevant error message

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
var squareElem
```

should be

```
var squareElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you havn't used squareElem  . You are using squareElement which is not defined 
your code is  : `var squareElem = Object.create`

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I updated coded with the relevant error message

Answer (score 0):

You're using [*Object.create*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) incorrectly. Assuming that you want the new object to inherit from *elem.prototype* (i.e. as if it's an instance of *elem*), then the object passed should be the object to use as the new object's `[[Prototype]]`, i.e. it should be *elem.prototype*, not *elem*.

Also, when you write:

```
Function.prototype.method
```

then *method* will be inherited by instances of Function (i.e. functions). Then you call:

```
squareElem.method
```

but *squareElem* is a plain object created by *Object.create*, so it's not a function and therefore doesn't inherit from *Function.prototype* and doesn't have a *method* method.